# is a Fortran subroutine with a dummy argument specified size array thread safe

Tags: memory, fortran, gfortran

The following code compiles in gfortran, with a warning about `large_array` being larger than the limit for a stack variable, stating that the array will be moved to static memory and is therefore not threadsafe:

```
subroutine stack_size_warning
  implicit none
  real :: large_array(65536)
  print *, large_array
end subroutine stack_size_warning
```

This subroutine however compiles with no errors or warnings, and I can call it with n values larger than 65536 without issue, at least in simple cases.

```
subroutine no_warning(n)
  implicit none
  integer :: n
  real :: automatic_array(n)
  print *, automatic_array
end subroutine no_warning
```

Is this second array threadsafe?  Where is the memory allocated for `automatic_array` in this second subroutine?  Is the memory allocated and deallocated on every call making it slower than if it was on the stack or if a preallocated array was passed in as a dummy argument?

Comment: With gfortran, you can use the -fdump-tree-original option to see the intermediate code.  The two routines, of course, are different and how they are handles differs.

Comment: "Where is the memory allocated for large_array in this second subroutine?" - unless something strange is happening somewhere in the calling tree for this routine, this routine as presented won't usually allocated any memory itself.

Comment: @steve thank you for the suggestion.  The tree dump appears fairly straight forward in answering my question as shown below

Comment: @IanBush, your observation is on the routine as presented was my thought as well, but conflicted with my intuition about what must happen.  Unless I am misreading something, the tree dump seems to indicate that `large_array` is allocated on the heap and then deallocated with every call to the subroutine

Comment: From where do you get that impression?

Comment: @IanBush, That is my reading of the line `D.3964 = (void * restrict) __builtin_malloc (MAX_EXPR <(unsigned long) (size.1 * 4), 1>);` in the try block and the line `__builtin_free ((void *) automatic_array);` in the finally block from the tree dump.  Am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I misread your routine and assumed the array was being passed as an argument, which is the way I would tend to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following program to test 3 scenarios, a subroutine with a small array on the stack, another with a large array over the stack limit and thus stored in static memory, and a third where a dummy argument specifies the size of an array defined inside the routine.

Here is that program:

```fortran
program main
  implicit none
  call small
  call large
  call automatic(65536)
end program main

subroutine small
  implicit none
  real :: small_array(10)
  small_array=1.
  print *, small_array
end subroutine small

subroutine large
  implicit none
  real :: large_array(65536)
  large_array=1.
  print *, large_array
end subroutine large

subroutine automatic(n)
  implicit none
  integer :: n
  real :: automatic_array(n)
  automatic_array=1.
  print *, automatic_array
end subroutine automatic
```

Using `steve`'s recommendation I compiled with a tree dump as follows:

```sh
gfortran array_dim_test.f90 -o array_dim_test -fdump-tree-original
```

The full dump is at the end, but to summarize what I see, the `automatic` subroutine has a try/finally block.  In the try block, a call to malloc allocates the memory, and in the finally block, the memory is freed.  So I guess this memory is allocated and deallocated on the heap with every call to the subroutine. This intuitively makes sense as how else would the program know what to do with this array that lives only in the subroutine, and whose size is defined in a call to the subroutine, but it is interesting to see the explicit calls in the tree dump.  This would appear to be thread-safe then, but perhaps also not the most efficient thing to do if this routine is called many times with the same array size parameter, allocating and deallocating memory with every call.

Here is the tree dump:

```c
__attribute__((fn spec (". w ")))
void automatic (integer(kind=4) & restrict n)
{
  void * restrict D.3964;
  integer(kind=8) ubound.0;
  integer(kind=8) size.1;
  real(kind=4)[0:D.3961] * restrict automatic_array;
  integer(kind=8) D.3961;
  bitsizetype D.3962;
  sizetype D.3963;

  try
    {
      ubound.0 = (integer(kind=8)) *n;
      size.1 = NON_LVALUE_EXPR <ubound.0>;
      size.1 = MAX_EXPR <size.1, 0>;
      D.3961 = size.1 + -1;
      D.3962 = (bitsizetype) (sizetype) NON_LVALUE_EXPR <size.1> * 32;
      D.3963 = (sizetype) NON_LVALUE_EXPR <size.1> * 4;
      D.3964 = (void * restrict) __builtin_malloc (MAX_EXPR <(unsigned long) (size.1 * 4), 1>);
      automatic_array = (real(kind=4)[0:D.3961] * restrict) D.3964;
      {
        integer(kind=8) D.3940;

        D.3940 = ubound.0;
        {
          integer(kind=8) S.2;

          S.2 = 1;
          while (1)
            {
              if (S.2 > D.3940) goto L.1;
              (*automatic_array)[S.2 + -1] = 1.0e+0;
              S.2 = S.2 + 1;
            }
          L.1:;
        }
      }
      {
        struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.3;

        dt_parm.3.common.filename = &"array_dim_test.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
        dt_parm.3.common.line = 27;
        dt_parm.3.common.flags = 128;
        dt_parm.3.common.unit = 6;
        _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.3);
        {
          integer(kind=8) D.3944;
          struct array01_real(kind=4) parm.4;

          D.3944 = ubound.0;
          parm.4.span = 4;
          parm.4.dtype = {.elem_len=4, .rank=1, .type=3};
          parm.4.dim[0].lbound = 1;
          parm.4.dim[0].ubound = D.3944;
          parm.4.dim[0].stride = 1;
          parm.4.data = (void *) &(*automatic_array)[0];
          parm.4.offset = -1;
          _gfortran_transfer_array_write (&dt_parm.3, &parm.4, 4, 0);
        }
        _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.3);
      }
    }
  finally
    {
      __builtin_free ((void *) automatic_array);
    }
}


__attribute__((fn spec (". ")))
void large ()
{
  static real(kind=4) large_array[65536];

  {
    integer(kind=8) S.5;

    S.5 = 1;
    while (1)
      {
        if (S.5 > 65536) goto L.2;
        large_array[S.5 + -1] = 1.0e+0;
        S.5 = S.5 + 1;
      }
    L.2:;
  }
  {
    struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.6;

    dt_parm.6.common.filename = &"array_dim_test.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
    dt_parm.6.common.line = 19;
    dt_parm.6.common.flags = 128;
    dt_parm.6.common.unit = 6;
    _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.6);
    {
      struct array01_real(kind=4) parm.7;

      parm.7.span = 4;
      parm.7.dtype = {.elem_len=4, .rank=1, .type=3};
      parm.7.dim[0].lbound = 1;
      parm.7.dim[0].ubound = 65536;
      parm.7.dim[0].stride = 1;
      parm.7.data = (void *) &large_array[0];
      parm.7.offset = -1;
      _gfortran_transfer_array_write (&dt_parm.6, &parm.7, 4, 0);
    }
    _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.6);
  }
}


__attribute__((fn spec (". ")))
void small ()
{
  real(kind=4) small_array[10];

  {
    integer(kind=8) S.8;

    S.8 = 1;
    while (1)
      {
        if (S.8 > 10) goto L.3;
        small_array[S.8 + -1] = 1.0e+0;
        S.8 = S.8 + 1;
      }
    L.3:;
  }
  {
    struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.9;

    dt_parm.9.common.filename = &"array_dim_test.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
    dt_parm.9.common.line = 12;
    dt_parm.9.common.flags = 128;
    dt_parm.9.common.unit = 6;
    _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.9);
    {
      struct array01_real(kind=4) parm.10;

      parm.10.span = 4;
      parm.10.dtype = {.elem_len=4, .rank=1, .type=3};
      parm.10.dim[0].lbound = 1;
      parm.10.dim[0].ubound = 10;
      parm.10.dim[0].stride = 1;
      parm.10.data = (void *) &small_array[0];
      parm.10.offset = -1;
      _gfortran_transfer_array_write (&dt_parm.9, &parm.10, 4, 0);
    }
    _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.9);
  }
}


__attribute__((fn spec (". ")))
void MAIN__ ()
{
  small ();
  large ();
  {
    static integer(kind=4) C.3993 = 65536;

    automatic (&C.3993);
  }
}


__attribute__((externally_visible))
integer(kind=4) main (integer(kind=4) argc, character(kind=1) * * argv)
{
  static integer(kind=4) options.11[7] = {2116, 4095, 0, 1, 1, 0, 31};

  _gfortran_set_args (argc, argv);
  _gfortran_set_options (7, &options.11[0]);
  MAIN__ ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The type of array you are interested in is an _automatic_ object. That's a useful search word for you, but it may make your answer (and question) clearer to others if used. For example, calling the subroutine `undefined`, `automatic` and its local variable `automatic_array`.

Comment: @francescalus, thank you.  That is a useful search term, and I see there is a lot of related information out there on the topic.  I appreciate the suggestion and have made the edits